# Custom domain routing to Flask server with custom domain always showing in address bar

Tags: python, web-services, dns, flask, tornado

I have a small home-server running Flask set up at IP `a.b.c.d`. I also have a domain name `xyz.com`.

Now I would like it so that when going to `xyz.com`, the user is served the content from `a.b.c.d`, with `xyz.com` still showing in the address bar. Similarly, when going to `xyz.com/foo` the content from `a.b.c.d/foo` should be shown, with `xyz.com/foo` showing in the address bar.

I have path forwarding activated at my domain name provider, so `xyz.com/foo` is correctly forwarded to `a.b.c.d/foo`, but when going there `a.b.c.d/foo` is shown in the address bar.

I'm currently running tornado, but I can switch to another server if it is necessary.

Is it possible to set up this kind of solution? Or is my only option to buy some kind of hosting?

Comment: You could do it with a reverse proxy but that requires access to the web server configuration. Why can't you point the domain at a.b.c.d?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with pointing the domain? I have domain forwarding and path forwarding set up, so the requests go through, but I still end up at `a.b.c.d/foo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve it by myself, but I'll add this as an answer since evidently someone thought it was a worthwhile question.

It turns out that it was just me that did not understand how DNS works and what the difference between DNS and domain forwarding is. At most domain hosts you can configure "domain forwarding", which sounds what precisely what you need but is NOT. Rather, for the simple usecase above, I went into the DNS Zone Records in the options and created a DNS Zone Record type A that pointed `xyz.com` to `a.b.c.d`. The change does not seem to have propagated entirely yet, but already on some devices I can see it working exactly how I want it to, so I will consider this issue resolved.

Comment: Update: now the DNS records have propagated everywhere, so it was indeed the right solution.